# Python - editing my range to print certain strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to edit my code to produce 10 lines. the first line starts at 0 and last ends at 9. Each line contains a string of 10 integers with 0 being the first and in successive order. I have produced the following and I cannot for the life of me figure out what to do next.

```
for i in range(10):
    for i in range(10):
        print(i,end=' ')
    print('\n')
```

which will output

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: Not sure exactly what the objective is? Could you clarify.

Comment: You shouldn't use the same variable name for nested loops.  That having been said, isn't this doing exactly what you said you wanted?  I'm not seeing a question here.

Comment: If you don't like the blank line between each line, don't print it; just `print()` at the end of your `for` loop instead of `print('\n')`.  Not sure what else could be the problem.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: So what I am trying to do is make it look like:
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
.............................
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9

Comment: If you want to get rid of the blank lines, change the `print('\n')` to just `print('')`  And don't use the same variable name for nested loops.

Comment: @ScrewzLewz Do you want them all to be on the same line?

Comment: @Reti43 He wants to know and he did not ask for a solution!

Comment: This is my very first post. I am a newbie with python. Please have a little tolerance while I get my bearings around this forum. I appreciate all the quick replies and assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to make each line 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0, and so on, your problem is reusing the variable for your for loops:

```
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        print(i,end=' ') #Now i is 0 for the first line, 1 for the next, and so on
    print('\n')
```

Comment: Thank you, that was what I was looking for. I do not know why I had struggled with that. Once I saw what you had written it clicked. I'm a python newb so I really appreciate it.

Comment: A more concise way is `print(" ".join(str(i) for i in range(10) for _ in range(10)))`

Comment: @zondo How this explain his problem!

Comment: @ScrewzLewz No problem! Enjoy learning python!

Comment: @WoLy I'm not trying to explain his problem (although this does fix it); I am simply pointing out a more concise solution.

Comment: @zondo Though that solution outputs all the numbers on the same line, which didn't seem to be what was desired.

Answer (score 0):

The  first variable is overwritten in each iteration, use a different variable in the second loop:

```
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        print(i,end=' ')
    print('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        print(i, end=' ')
    print('')
```

Note that the inner loop uses a *different* variable name, allowing you to access the outer loop variable.  Here's the output:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 
6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 
7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 
8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
```